# Random number generator based on input Java

Tags: java, random, generator

I'm looking for a random number generator that I can create with a seed and takes two inputs x and y to generate the number. I need the same number every time I use the same inputs with the same seed.

I'm using this to randomly assign textures across a coordinate grid so I need it to be the same every time. So every time I'm at x = 100, y = 120 in the same seed I need the same random number so the same texture is assigned in that spot.

I think why I’m looking for is some kind of basic procedural generating technique. I can’t use the Random class because it gives me a number stream that I have to nextInt() until I get to the one I want. Then if I need one of the numbers that I passed I’d have to start again. This would be a huge problem if I was far from the origin in a space with 1,000,000 tiles.

Comment: Random and same don’t go along, you asking to generate random number but want it to be same under condition.

Comment: Doesn't it sound rather like a kind of hash? What's wrong with simply multiplying x and y for example? Do you need to avoid collisions?

Comment: Essentially, it is a random distribution function for three values.

Comment: *I need the same number every time I use the same inputs with the same seed.* - that's what seed-based random generators do. If you provide the same seed, they generate the same sequence. If you find it otherwise, please show the relevant code.

Comment: How many random numbers will you need to generate based on a single seed?

Comment: @sp00m basically I’m generating terrain for a planet. And I want something that can generate different planets with different seeds. So if I just multiplied the coordinates then every planet would have its terrain textures distributed the same way.

Comment: @tevemadar I wanted to use this but a number stream won’t work for me. There will be at least tens of thousands of tiles and if I want to start somewhere that’s not close to the origin then it will have to step the stream like 50,000 times. Plus if I don’t save the results somewhere I’d have to start again and step it 45,000 times if I need a number already passed. 

Basically I need some kind of basic procedural generation technique.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk tens or hundreds of thousands. Not exactly sure but a ton.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest multiplying or taking a sum of two random values based on seed.

```
public int random(int x, int y) {
        int i = new Random(x).nextInt();
        int j = new Random(y).nextInt();
        return i * j;
}
```

Comment: How about `return new Random((long) x *(long) y).nextInt();`

Comment: This is pretty close to working but wouldn’t I get the same result if I was at 200, 75 and at 75, 200?

Comment: @JackThompson: Yes, that is a downside.

Answer (score 0):

So you don't wanna a random number you just wanna a number based on 2 ints. This can be done by multiply then, and then map them to the max. Of course when doing this you will get ouptut being the same but I guess this is meant since you proberly don't have thousands of tiles. So I made this function you can call with `getTile(x,y,maxX,maxY,max);` where x and y are just the coords, maxX and maxY are the size of the grid and max is the number of different textures.

```
public static int getTexture(int x, int y, int maxX, int maxY, int max){
  float texture=x*y;
  texture/=maxX*maxY;
  texture*=max;
  return (int)texture;
}
```

Comment: I’ll probably use something simple like this for now until I find something more random. The thing is I do have thousands of tiles. also I’ll want to use this number generator for other things in the future where the randomness is more important.

Answer (score 0):

If your main concern is that coordinate pairs `x,y` and `y,x` should not give the same result, combine them in an asymmetric way. As you write about graphics and textures, you may have encountered expressions like `x+y*width` when you index a conceptually 2D object (texture, screen, something), which is actually stored in an 1D array. So as long as you have a `width`, an upper bound for `x`, you can just use this expression for initializing `Random`:

```
public static int random(int x,int y,int xbound,int range)
{
    return new Random(x+y*xbound).nextInt(range);
}
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    for(int y=0;y<=10;y++)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<=10;x++)
            System.out.printf("%4d",random(x,y,1000,101));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

produces

> ```
>   67  97   5  36  88  17  27  57   8  38  48
>   84  14  23  54   4  35  44  75  58  88  98
>   63  94   2  33  85  14  24  54   5  35  45
>   17  47  57  87  38  69  78   7  27  57  67
>   32  63  72   2  54  84  93  23  75   4  14
>   53  83  93  22  74   3  13  43  27  57  66
>    9  39  49  79  30  61  70   0  51  82  91
>   29  60  69 100  50  81  90  20  39  70  79
>   45  75  85  14  66  97   5  35  87  17  26
>   40  71  80  10  62  92   1  31  14  45  54
>   20  50  60  90  41  72  81  10  62  93   1
> ```

as its [output](https://ideone.com/dFA0mP).

This will work out of the box until `x` and `y` stay below `xbound=65536`. Above that, you can just write `long xbound`, and it will work up to 16 million. After that you would better use a bit shift and an exclusive or, because the parts of the sum will start to overlap.